# How to open the help for an operator in R?

Tags: r

I usually use `?givenFunction` to find the help corresponding to a given function. But how to do for operators like `+`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to surround it by quotes, double quotes or backquotes:

```
?`+`
?'+'
?"+"
```

and same in `help()`